# Different behavior in C regex vs C++ regex using extended POSIX grammar

Tags: c++, c, regex, c++11, posix

I am seeing different results when using the C POSIX regex library and the C++ standard library implementation. Here is my code:

```cpp
string pattern = "\\s";
string testString = " ";

regex_t cre;
int status = regcomp(&cre, pattern.c_str(), REG_EXTENDED);
int result = (regexec(&cre, testString.c_str(), 0, 0, 0) == 0);
cout << "C: " << result << endl;

regex re(pattern, regex_constants::extended);
smatch sm;
cout << "C++: " << regex_search(testString, sm, re) << endl;
```

The C portion successfully matches the whitespace, but the C++ one throws this error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
> what():  Unexpected escape character.

I understand that the string literal is escaped meaning that the actual regex that is used in pattern matching should be `\s`. I also only see this issue when using POSIX extended grammar. In the C++ version, if I do not specify POSIX extended grammar when constructing the regex, it defaults to ECMAScript grammar and is able to parse correctly.

What is going on here?

Comment: Good question! I don't know the complete answer, but I can tell you that `\s` is *not* an escape sequence defined by the POSIX ERE spec ( https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04 ). Naively I would have expected *neither* `regexec` nor `regex_search` to recognize it.

Comment: But even though neither library should successfully match the test string to the pattern, I see no reason for either to fail with an error, either.  `\s` is a valid POSIX extended regex that matches a single 's' character.  So it seems you're looking at two regex libraries with different bugs affecting the same pattern.

Answer (score 1):

`regex_constants::extended` triggers the [POSIX ERE regex syntax](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) that does not support [shorthand character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html). Note the C `regex.h` module supports `\s` as a non-standard extension.

To match any whitespace in `regex_constants::extended` enabled POSIX ERE flavor, you need to use `string pattern = "[[:space:]]"`.

However, you should just rely on the [default ECMAScript flavor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript), and use

```cpp
regex re(pattern);
// or
regex re(pattern, std::regex::ECMAScript);
```

Comment: How do you know that "the C regex.h module supports \s as a non-standard extension" ?  OP does not specify a C library and I can think of at least two alternative explanations.

Comment: @zwol From SO experience, when one uses `regcomp(&cre, pattern.c_str(), REG_EXTENDED)`, it is 99.9999999% `regex.h`. It does support some PCRE-like shorthand classes

Comment: Of course it's `regex.h`, that's not the issue.  The issue is that this is the first I've ever heard of a `regex.h` implementation giving `\s` its Perl meaning.  It has to be an implementation extension and we have no idea which implementation OP has.

Answer (score 0):

In Posix REs

> The effect of any ordinary character being preceded by an escape is undefined.

(from [boost docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/basic_extended.html))

> 9.4.2 ERE Ordinary Characters

> An ordinary character is an ERE that matches itself. An ordinary character is any character in the supported character set, except for the ERE special characters listed in ERE Special Characters. The interpretation of an ordinary character preceded by an unescaped  ( '\' ) is undefined, except in the context of a bracket expression (see ERE Bracket Expression).

(from [posix docs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) )

Similar wording applies to BREs.

So both are posix compliant, as your RE is undefined in effect.